# URL losing port number in every page load

Tags: .net, asp.net, url, port-number

I'm currently taking care of a certain local website.

The default port has been changed, and can no longer be not included in the URL due to technical reasons, so now i'm using a certain port in the end of the IP at the URL, for example

```
100.100.100.100/website.aspx
```

no longer works (which accessed 80 by default)

```
100.100.100.100:81/website.aspx
```

with the port, works.

Works, though I can't click in any link or anything and the port vanishes (new page doesn't load). Then I keep the same URL and just include the port at the end of the IP and it works again, until I click in another link inside of it.

I have access to changing each link, but I guess that would not be the right approach.

How should I procceed ?

**--[EDIT]--**

All URL's are already relative, and the whole issue of this question is not applicable in IE, this only happens on other browsers.

/website.aspx

What I said about changing each link would be something like

```
:10/website.aspx
```

But I really don't know..

**--[EDIT]--**

As requested:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="link" NavigateUrl="~/folder/folder/page.aspx" />
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the link tags from a page?

Comment: @Just Some Guy as requested, question edited.

Comment: Ramires What I meant was: Can you post an example of the link tags that are actually being generated and sent to the client? That is, the actual href="" attributes in the output HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type:

```
http://1.2.3.4/website.asp
```

That is equivalent to

```
http://1.2.3.4:80/website.asp
```

If you need to specify a different port you must include it explicitly in the URL.

**Option 1**
If all your links are of the form

```
http://1.2.3.4/website.asp
```

You'll need to change them to

```
http://1.2.3.4:10/website.asp
```

**Option 2**

Option 2 is to change all links to be relative so instead of having:

```
http://1.2.3.4/anotherpage.asp
```

You change it to just

```
/anotherpage.asp
```

The browser will then use the same IP and port number for each request.

Option 2 is preferred since it makes sites robust against exactly these types of moves.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a Binding in the IIS. (I assume you are using IIS for this)

**Edit**: I assume that you have set a binding to port 10. Add an alternative binding without port (if that is possible. if not, add a binding for port 80) I hope this helps.

Comment: I am. could you please elaborate on that? edit this answer or send me an e-mail (on my profile)

Comment: This port 10 is made up for this question. It was 80 and now it's 81. There is no binding because 80 is the default.

Answer (score -1):

Internet Explorer doesn't like addresses whose first colon isn't part of the scheme definition ("http://", or "https://").  You're starting your links with "http://" (or "https://")?  If not, it might contribute to the problems you're having.